# Handling error on a vue component render function

Tags: vue.js

I have a FormBuilder Vue component that uses the h render function; this component resolves the modelValue programmatically with a method `resolveModel()`. This method throws an error if the modelValue is not found in the Form object.

```js
// Component Setup Method

/**
 * Resolve the model key from the form object
 * @throws {Error}
 */
const resolveModel = () => {
  const output = // Resolve value from the form object

  // If no value was found in the form object, throw an error
  if (typeof output === 'undefined') {
    throw new Error(
      `FormBuilder: Model key "${props.field.id}" not found in form object`
    )
  }

  // Return the resolved value
  return output
}

return () => h('Component', {
  modelValue: resolveModel(), <-- How to handle exception thrown here?
})
```

I am using vitest, and I test that the error is thrown with the test below.

```js
it('throws an error if the model value does not exist in the form object', async () => {
  try {
    await wrapper.setProps({
      field: {
        id: 'rental.vendor_id',
      },
    })
  } catch (e) {
    expect(e.message).toBe(
      'FormBuilder: Model key "rental.vendor_id" not found in form object'
    )
  }
})
```

The above test passes but I still get two warnings in the console `[Vue warn]: Unhandled error during execution of render function` and `[Vue warn]: Unhandled error during execution of scheduler flush. This is likely a Vue internals bug. Please open an issue at https://new-issue.vuejs.org/?repo=vuejs/core`

Any idea how to catch this error to suppress the console warnings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap your render function under a try / catch block to handle the exception. But you'll need to decide what to render in this case.

```
return () => {
  try {
    return h('Component', {
      modelValue: resolveModel(), <-- How to handle exception thrown here?
    })
  } catch (renderError) {
    // Handle the exception, but it has to return something to render
    return h()
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, yes this gets rid of the warning but after thinking about it a bit more, I think it makes sense for my Error not to be caught since I want to halt execution.